# Falling sand in pygame, particle created and dropped every time the mouse button is pressed

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to make a code where with every mouse click, a circle is drawn and dropped to the bottom. I have problems with that because i cant think of how a new particle can be drawn while one is falling. I have no idea how to code this therefore i at least need an idea of how this could be done. This is what i have got up to but im very confused what to do next.

```
import pygame, time

class Material(object):

    def __init__(self, name, radius, gravity):
        self.name = name
        self.radius = radius
        self.gravity = gravity


sand = Material("Sand", 5, 2)

def game():
    pygame.init()
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 650))
    pygame.display.set_caption("***Sandbox***")
    event = pygame.event.wait()
    velocity = 0
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit() 
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                x, y = event.pos
                print(event.pos)
                pygame.draw.circle(win, (194, 178, 128), (x, y), sand.radius)
                pygame.display.update()
                while y >= 0 and y < 645:
                    win.fill((0,0,0,))
                    y += velocity
                    velocity += sand.gravity
                    print(x, y)
                    if y > 645:
                        y = 645
                        velocity = 0
                    pygame.draw.circle(win, (194, 178, 128), (x, y), sand.radius)
                    pygame.display.update()


game()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object Oriented Programming is your friend in this case. You have created a class `Material`, but you are not making full use of it, since you are never creating more than one instance of your class.

First, let your class store the coordinates of the falling sand, which I'd say are the most important attributes in this case, since each sand will have its own coordinates.

```
class Material(object):
    def __init__(self, name, pos, radius, gravity):
        self.name = name
        self.x = pos[0]
        self.y = pos[1]
        self.radius = radius
        self.gravity = gravity
```

Then in you code create a list (empty at the beginning) where you are going to store all the `Material` instances created during the execution of the program.

Your `game` function needs several editing:

- First, use the event `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP`, and not `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`. Since you are in the event loop, better to use pygame event system.
- The logic to draw the materials should be outside the event loop. The event loop should only create a `Material` instance and add it to the list.
- Move the drawing logic in the main loop. Don't move each particle all along to the bottom of the screen with a loop, but loop over the list of particles to move each particle by one step towards the bottom (i.e. adding `gravity` to `y` coordinate).
- `pygame.quit()` closes pygame, but not the program. Use `sys.exit()` to exit from the program without errors.
- Add a [pygame.time.Clock](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) to slow down the animation.

So your final code should look like this:

```
import sys
import pygame

class Material(object):
    def __init__(self, name, pos, radius, gravity):
        self.name = name
        self.x = pos[0]
        self.y = pos[1]
        self.radius = radius
        self.gravity = gravity

allsands = []

def game():
    pygame.init()
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 650))
    pygame.display.set_caption("***Sandbox***")
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                print(event.pos)
                allsands.append(Material("Sand", event.pos, 5, 2))

        win.fill((0,0,0,))
        for sand in allsands:
            pygame.draw.circle(win, (194, 178, 128), (sand.x, sand.y), sand.radius)
            if sand.y >=0 and sand.y < 645:
                sand.y += sand.gravity

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(50)

game()
```

This is the result:

[image]

In principle further edits can be done to make your `Material` a real [Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and use a [sprite Group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) instead of a list to store them, but I tried to not rewrite completely your code.

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I wanted and you explained everything really good. Thank you so so so much for spending your time helping me with this! I really appreciate it.